# Crashing during particle bake (not from memory)

Tags: animation, particles, baking

I am baking particles, 10000 of them, following a simple curve guide over 1600 frames. They are halos for the moment, as the shape / object doesn't affect anything.

When I hit bake, it begins to bake some frames, sometimes gets halfway, and then crashes. I am baking with Disk Usage on. I know I am *not* running out of memory, as I have 16gb, have literally everything else except Blender shut down, and watching both Blender's usage, and on Task Manager, it doesn't exceed a gigabyte.

I do have a fairly intense scene, maybe 1 million tris, but that has not caused issues in any way.

I have tried setting compression on the bake, both Lite and Heavy, but to no avail.

I am not out of Disk Space either, although I do have another bake from the same file in the folder it's baking to.

Any and all help is appreciated!

UPDATE: [Here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LQnMQQqR3FBoYStC7aHRZHQQsyLGOSml/view?usp=sharing) the link to the file, let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I think you should supply a blend file and crash log (if any).  GPU probably crashed.

Comment: Uploaded a blend file, with nothing else than what is needed (it still crashes). Where might I find a crash log?

Comment: I press "Bake" and "Bake All Dynamics" for "Plane.003". it doesn't crash for me.

Comment: Riiight... I tried it on two seperate computers (one, a laptop with a mobile 2060), and the other a PC with a Titan, and both are crashing... So I didn't think it'd be a problem of that.

Comment: You read where to find crash log : https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/dev/troubleshooting/crash.html (Crash Log - section).  I have 0 experience, but some pro might find the log useful - if you are lucky that it prints something related.

Comment: Graphic driver updated?  I encountered some crash issue in Blender that can be fixed just by updating it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your crash, although the file I downloaded is not as described.  There are two particle systems, both rendering "object"-- 1, a 2x subdivision plane, the other, a higher-than-default-resolution metaball (which is probably where your problems are coming from, if my spidey sense counts for anything.)  Baking either individually, or baking all dynamics, works fine.  Memory usage climbs significantly during bake, but by less than a GB.  Vers. 2.90.

Comment: Running on 2.91 and I too cannot reproduce any crash